# Начисление дохода

Tags: php

подскажите мой код делает начисление ежедневно по вкладам, проблема в том что если юзер купит два тарифа одинаковых начисление идет только по одному как это исправить?

```
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM db_users_b WHERE id = $user_id");
$user_data = $db->FetchArray();
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `db_tarif_buy_50` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND DATE(`date`) < CURDATE() AND `date_end` >= NOW()");
$count_tarifs2 = $db->NumRows();

if($count_tarifs2 > 0){
    $data_tarifs2 = array();
    while($result2 = $db->FetchArray()){
      $data_tarifs2[] = $result2;
    }
    foreach($data_tarifs2 as $key2 => $array2){
      $db->Query("SELECT * FROM `db_tarif_profit_50` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND `tarif` = '".$array2['tarif']."' AND DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()");
      if($db->NumRows() == 0){
        $db->Query("SELECT * FROM `db_tarif_50` WHERE `id` = '".$array2['tarif']."'");
        if($db->NumRows() > 0){
          $data_tarif2 = $db->FetchArray();
          $percentprofit2 = ($array2['sum'] * ($data_tarif2['profit']/100));
          $nach2 = 1;
          $db->Query("INSERT INTO `db_tarif_profit_50` (`user_id`,`tarif`,`amount`, `nach`) VALUES ('$user_id','".$data_tarif2['id']."','".$percentprofit2."','".$nach2."')");
          $db->query("UPDATE `db_users_b` SET `money_b` = `money_b` + '".($percentprofit2/2)."', `money_p` = `money_p` + '".($percentprofit2/2)."' WHERE `id` = '$user_id'");
          $db->query("UPDATE `db_tarif_buy_50` SET `nachisleno` = `nachisleno` + '".$nach2."' WHERE `id` = '".$data_tarif2['id']."' AND `user_id` = '$user_id'");
       } 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: а зачем одному юзеру покупать два одинаковых тарифа ?

Comment: он выбирает тариф и вводит туда сумму

Comment: https://wampi.ru/image/R6GqmD0

Comment: А вы не на отсутствие записей проверяйте, а сделайте запрос который вам вернет все тарифы, по которым начислений еще не было за сегодня, т.е. что то типа `select * from db_tarif_50 t where not exists(select 1 from db_tarif_profit_50 p where p.tarif=t.id and p.date >= CURDATE() and p.date < CURDATE()+interval 1 day)`.

Comment: А еще стоит почитать про тарнзакции и начать их использовать, сейчас у вас если что то пойдет не так, например перезагрузится сервак во время выполнения скрипта, запросто могут не пройти какие то начисления или даже оказаться несогласованное состояние БД, например запись в profit будет, а сумму в users не исправят. И вообще сумму в users стоило бы вести не php скриптом, а триггерами на всех таблицах, данные в которых на нее влияют

Comment: Кстати если update users и tarif_buy вынести в триггер на profit, то все начисления свелись бы к единственному sql запросу вида `insert into db_tarif_profit_50(....) select ... from db_tarif_50 where not exists ...` и ни одной строчки на php не понадобилось

Comment: я в это деле еще 0 подскажите что здесь  select * from db_tarif_50 t where not exists(select 1 from db_tarif_profit_50 p where p.tarif=t.id and p.date >= CURDATE() and p.date < CURDATE()+interval 1 day) означает p t

Comment: А вы можете подсказать как сделать что бы кроном начисление было?